# How do I replace a Python property without a setter for an instance?

Tags: python, properties

Given the existing source code (that I cannot modify), how do I dynamically replace the property at *instance* level (not class, because that breaks stateless assumptions everywhere)?

The following naive approach raises `AttributeError: property 'my_property' of 'MyClass' object has no setter`

```py
from abc import abstractmethod, ABC


class Parent(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def my_property(self) -> int:
        ...

    @abstractmethod
    def my_method(self) -> int:
        ...


class MyClass(Parent):
    @property
    def my_property(self) -> int:
        return 1

    def my_method(self) -> int:
        return 1


def new_property_impl(self):
    return 2

# Create an instance of MyClass
obj = MyClass()

# Dynamically replace the my_property method with new_property_impl
obj.my_property = property(new_property_impl)

# Expected result
print(obj.my_property)  # 2
```

Comment: Can't it be a subclass instead?

Comment: I can freely modify the parent class, but the child classes (of which there are many) all have a `@property` that implements the parent's abstract property

Comment: Yeah but you could make a subclass of child classes that reimplements the property and leaves everything else as is.

Comment: ''I can freely modify the parent class" - is that the one that you posted? if not post the parent class

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't.

This is how the language is designed. The Properties(or [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) in general) have to be defined at class level. Otherwise, you won't see the effect of descirptors and you just get the `property` object back:

```py
class A:
    pass

obj = A()

obj.myprop = property(lambda x: 10)
print(obj.myprop)   # <property object at 0x7f683de0a4d0>
```

But if you have a property defined in the class(because properties are "Data Descriptors", Python will first catch that attribute:

```py
class A:
    @property
    def myprop(self):
        return 20

obj = A()
obj.__dict__["myprop"] = property(lambda x: 10)
print(obj.myprop)  # 20
```

So there is no such thing as properties as instance attributes.

---

Edit:

If you decided to modify the class using decorator, here is an option:

```py
def change_property(cls):
    setattr(cls, "myprop", property(lambda x: 30))
    return cls

class A:
    @property
    def myprop(self):
        return 20

obj = A()
A = change_property(A)
print(obj.myprop)  # 30
```

Comment: Could it indirectly be "decorated" in some way then (but without modifying the source code for `MyClass`? The original _can_ stay, but it just has to do additional things, e.g. setting some attributes

Comment: @komodovaran_ Yes you can decorate the class but you said you don't want the class to be modified as all the instances are then affected. Whether you modify the source code directly or modify it by a decorator, all the instances will see the change.

Comment: @komodovaran_ Added a solution using a decorator.

Answer (score 0):

Properties are defined at class level, and can't be configured per instance (unless, or course, their getter and setter are made in a way to call a function bound to an instance, as an attribute).

The "one and obvious" way of overriding a property is by subclassing the class defining the instance in first place, and then using an instance of this subclass instead.

Python, in some cases, for normal user defined instances, using no slots or metaclasses, *do* allow one to change the class of an existing instance. This is defined language behavior, and could be done at runtime even in a production setting.

What, however, the language is not designed to do, is to create "disposable classes": if you happen to create code that will create "one use" classes over and over again you will have a resource leak (including memory).

But if the number of different custom setters you need to create is limited, it is possible to: get an instance; create dynamically a class which modifies your target property setter; change the class of that instance to this new dynamic class - it will still behave as an instance of the original super-class, simply because that is how oop works.

```
...

class MyClass(Parent):
    @property
    def my_property(self) -> int:
        return 1

    def my_method(self) -> int:
        return 1


def new_property_impl(self):
    return 2

obj = MyClass()


# create a new property object using the new getter standalone
# function as getter. (this will preserve a setter and deleter, if any,
# in the new object, just like inheritance and overriding would do)
new_property = MyClass.my_property.getter(new_property_impl)

# Create a new class dynamically, using the new property - 
transient_class = type("transient", (MyClass,), {"my_property": new_property} )

# Change the existing instance's class to be the new subclass:
obj.__class__ = transient_class

print(obj.my_property)
```

(This has printed "2" for me, as expected). Again, as I said above, you can't do this in code that will run continuously, like, inside a function used to create a server response. But if the number of setter variants you have is fixed, you can keep track of the classes already created in a dictionary and just re-use them: in this way you will also prevent the creation of unlimited new classes.